# iOS upload a file from application

Tags: iphone, file-upload

I am developing an application whereby i want to upload an arbitrary file to the server using my application. However, it primarily appears that iOS does not expose the file system to the application.

Is there any way to accomplish this task ? (Please remember here that I do not know the name of file). It is a kind of browse for files - select a file - upload it.

If it is possible in iOS, is there any open source component/library available to facilitate this task ?

Comment: how to get file...? may be it depending on file type or its mime-type also then lots of similar quetion of uploading file from app to server.

Comment: @Nitin Gohel - Please give link to one of them. I tried a lot but could not find an exact question.

Comment: which type of file you want to upload i mean Video,audio,txt,pdf,doc

Comment: It can be any file, say even executables, zip, rar files or anything as such. I have also read your answer but it appears that you are considering only images.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file system to access on iOS, unless you are contemplating a jail broken App, other than the files you create as part of your App.  You would not normally let a User browse your App's files but it you did you'd implement a App-specific approach to the browsing.